# How do I apply a datum adjustment to multiple CAD files in ArcMap?

Tags: python-2.7, cad, map-projections, arcmap

I can create a world file (.wld) to adjust the projection of a CAD file to match my basemap in ArcMap. However, I have many CAD files to do this to. How can I automate or loop applying the datum adjustment factor to all of my CAD files?

I've tried:

-Turning CAD poly lines into rasters and using the Shift tool. (Time intensive and didn't work.)

-Researching Python code (in "Python: Scripting for ArcGIS).

-Searching on the Internet.

no code as of yet

I want to be able to use ArcMap's Model Builder or a Python for loop to move the CAD files in the display by a set factor.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It's actually quite simple, but the instructions are not easy to navigate to on ESRI's help site.

Instead of creating a world file (.wld) for a single CAD file, you can create a universal world file named esri_cad.wld. As long as it is in the same workspace as your CAD files, it will adjust all of them.

Here is the link: Wile this is for an older version of ArcMap, it also works with 10.5.
[World Files for ArcMap](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=World_files)